# How to import WithHeadings in custom laravel class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have a file ExcelConclusions.php in path: `/app/Library/Excel` with content:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Library;
    
    use App\Library\Excel;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    
    
    class ExcelConclusions extends Excel implements WithHeadings
    {}
```

I always get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ExcelConclusions.php line 18:
Interface 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings' not found
```

How to import this interface?

There is row in providers: `[Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class]`

I have used [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html) instruction.

Comment: Imports and Exports have different `Concerns`: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/concerns.html  vs https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/concerns.html. Did you mean to use `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow`? Beyond that, make sure you're on the right version (3.1), and check your `vendor/maatwebsite` folder to see if that Interface is actually there.

Comment: There is interface  `WithHeadings` in Laravel 5.3 and  `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm not seeing anything in the Docs for version 2.1 for `WithHeadings`... Do you have a link? Also, if you're using Version `2.1`, don't use the documentation for 3.1; they're not compatible.

Comment: Seems you are right, Bu I need to leave this version, so how to change columns name?

Comment: Do you have docs for 2.1?

Comment: They're on the same page, you just need to swap the Version via the Dropdown in the navbar.

Comment: Thank you, so for 1.2 there is not any functionality to change columns name

Comment: Yeah, 2.1 is a little lacking in the Documentation department, and I'm afraid I don't have a local project to test this one either... Hopefully someone will be able to help you though!